# How to get State specific result with Google autocomplete place api ios?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, filter, google-places-api

I am using below code to filter country data and i got success. and I am working on Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8.0 .

```
        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = self

        let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filter.type = .Address
        filter.country = "US"

        autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

        self.presentViewController(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want more.

1) I want to filter particular state data (Like, Michigan) in United State, so any idea how can I filter it. I had suffering internet at my best but i can not get it.

Wishing your reply

Comment: Hii you find any solution for this ? because i have to do same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the geolocation of that specific location (in your case Michigan) and set a radius and apply strictBounds in the parameters section and it'll display only results within the region.

Comment: But when there are no results in that region it displays other results..If at all you strictly want to restrict the you have to provide those parameters.

Comment: I changed my code in "didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace " where i compare  "field.name" with state "MI" or "Michigan" (String).
If it match than go further.